# NSUserdefaults does not open

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

This is **class 1** here I save my strings and variables I am pretty sure everything is ok in this class.

```
-(void)SaveTextBox:(NSString*)string :(NSString*)stringsave
{ 
    NSString *savestring = string;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:savestring forKey:stringsave];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
- (IBAction)btnSaveTeamNames:(id)sender
{
[self SaveTextBox:tbTeam1.text :@"save1"];
[self SaveTextBox:tbTeam2.text :@"save2"];
[self SaveTextBox:tbTeam3.text :@"save3"];
[self SaveTextBox:tbTeam4.text :@"save4"];
[self SaveTextBox:tbTeam5.text :@"save5"];
[self SaveTextBox:tbTeam6.text :@"save6"];
[self SaveTextBox:tbTeam7.text :@"save7"];
[self SaveTextBox:tbTeam8.text :@"save8"];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:TeamAmount] forKey:@"teamAmount"];
}
```

**Class 2**

This is where I try to load the NSUserDefaults(Probably the mistake is in this class)

For some reason the labels don't get changed when the slider moves, Also I made a viewdidload call on my void to load the labels with standard saved strings but they do not load either.

```
@synthesize lblTeamOne;
@synthesize lblTeamTwo;
@synthesize sliderTeamOneOutlet;
@synthesize sliderTeamTwoOutlet;

-(void)loadTeams:(NSString*)location:(NSString*)lblname
{

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *loadstring = [defaults objectForKey:location];
lblname = loadstring;
}

-(void)sliderdisplay:(UISlider *)sliderOutlet :(NSString *)lblName
{
if(0 < sliderOutlet.value && 1 >= sliderOutlet.value)
{
    [self loadTeams:@"save1" :lblName];

}
if(1 < sliderOutlet.value && 2 >= sliderOutlet.value)
{
    [self loadTeams:@"save2" :lblName];

}
if(2 < sliderOutlet.value && 3 >= sliderOutlet.value)
{
    [self loadTeams:@"save3" :lblName];

}
if(3 < sliderOutlet.value && 4 >= sliderOutlet.value)
{
    [self loadTeams:@"save4" :lblName];

}
if(4 < sliderOutlet.value && 5 >= sliderOutlet.value)
{
    [self loadTeams:@"save5" :lblName];

}
if(5 < sliderOutlet.value && 6 >= sliderOutlet.value)
{
    [self loadTeams:@"save6" :lblName];

}
if(6 < sliderOutlet.value && 7 >= sliderOutlet.value)
{
    [self loadTeams:@"save7" :lblName];

}
if(7 < sliderOutlet.value && 8 >= sliderOutlet.value)
{
    [self loadTeams:@"save8" :lblName];

}
}
-(void)loadMaximum
{

int teamAmount = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"teamAmount"] intValue];
NSNumber *yourNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:teamAmount];
float sliderMaximumDigital = [yourNumber floatValue];
[sliderTeamOneOutlet setMaximumValue:sliderMaximumDigital];
[sliderTeamTwoOutlet setMaximumValue:sliderMaximumDigital];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self loadTeams:@"save1" :lblTeamOne.text];
[self loadTeams:@"save1" :lblTeamTwo.text];
[self loadMaximum];
}
```

Comment: There are severl issues in your code (among other things the way you declare your methods with nothing before your arguments – it is understood by the compiler but makes your own code much less readable). You are also passing arguments where you want to either pass them by reference, or provide a return value instead. What your code below seem to do is just to re-assign all the time lblname to a new string. Nothing more. No labels involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a pointer to your `UILabel` object so it can be updated:

```
-(void)loadTeams:(NSString*)location label:(UILabel*)label
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring = [defaults objectForKey:location];
    label.text = loadstring;
}
...

[self loadTeams:@"save1" label:lblTeamOne];
```

Comment: Just asking but was this a bad question every time I ask this kind of questions I seem to get downvoted.

Comment: @harry No the question you asked was fine; you provided enough information to solve it.  Some people like to downvote if they don't like the code you provide, which is wrong for them to do.  People are like that here I'm afraid.